# Problem using typeorm on nestJs Can't import Entity Repo

Tags: typescript, nestjs

[Error importing EntityRepository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Igdn.png)

I need to use that decorator but vs code doesn't recognizes. I have @nestjs/typeorm installed

Comment: just put your cursor right above it, man.

Answer (score 0):

It's been deprecated. You have to use the `Repository.extend` function.

[image]